# Swipe Refresh для WebView

Tags: java, android

Помогите сделать страницы браузера.
Чтобы не делал одни ошибки вылезают в android studio.

MainActivity

```
package dub.dbcenter;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);        // отключили прокрутку
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);      // отключили прокрутку
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  // включили JavaScript
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);  // включили localStorage и т.п.
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);       // отключили зум, т.к. нормальные приложения подобным функционалом не обладают
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);   // отключили поддержку вкладок.
    // Т.к. пользователь должен сидеть в SPA приложении
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    webView.loadUrl("http://site.ru");
}


}
```

ActivityMain

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView">
</WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Что-то получилось, Swipe Refresh работает, но почему-то чёрный экран и сайт не открывает, что не правильно?

```
package dub.dbcenter;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);        // отключили прокрутку
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);      // отключили прокрутку
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  // включили JavaScript
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);  // включили localStorage и т.п.
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);       // отключили зум, т.к. нормальные приложения подобным функционалом не обладают
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);   // отключили поддержку вкладок.
    // Т.к. пользователь должен сидеть в SPA приложении
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    webView.loadUrl("http://site.ru");

    mSwipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    mSwipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    mSwipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(
            R.color.blue_swipe, R.color.green_swipe,
            R.color.orange_swipe, R.color.red_swipe);

}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    Log.d("my_tag", "refresh");
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            // stop refresh
            mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 7000);
}

}
```

Comment: Какие именно ошибки у вас происходят?

Comment: Я делал по разным урокам, а начинаю прикручивать к моему коду, постоянно что-то красным подсвечивается. В основном делаю методом тыка, знаний не хватает.

Comment: @steep так вы читайте что там пишется. В основном описание ошибок самодостаточно и можно сразу понять в чём дело. Если у вас мало опыта, то пробуйте гуглить ошибки изначально. И да, учитесь гуглить лучше сразу по английски. Так намного быстрее будете решать проблемы.

Comment: Не понимаю я ошибки